# How can I see the query that's being run?

Tags: 7, hooks, views

I'm using hook_views_query_alter(), and I'd really like to print somewhere (screen, error log, whatever) the query that's being run based on the alterations. I've tried dpm($query), but that gives me the whole krumo tree - all I want is the query - i.e. "select x, y from z where a = 2". Possible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The [`views_plugin_query_default`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21views%21plugins%21views_plugin_query_default.inc/class/views_plugin_query_default/7) class has a [`query()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21views%21plugins%21views_plugin_query_default.inc/function/views_plugin_query_default%3A%3Aquery/7) method that will take the parameters currently held in the object and provide you with a standard [`SelectQuery`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!select.inc/class/SelectQuery/7) (un-executed of course).

Since the `SelectQuery` class implements the magic [`__toString()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring) method you can then cast it directly to a string, which will be the SQL query itself:

```
$select_query = $query->query();
$query_string = (string)$select_query;
dpm($query_string);
```

Comment: Thanks very much. I got an error: "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in views_plugin_query_default->query() (line 1217 of /home/www/expo/sites/all/modules/contrib/views/plugins/views_plugin_query_default.inc)." But it did show the query, which is all I care about.